# how do i run a development rails app / website on an ipod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ipad, apache, ios5

I have a app / site that i am running on my local imac and i want to test it on my ipad browser.

Can connect to my imac localhost rails app throught the wifi with my ipad ?   If so how!! ?

My app is a multi tenant app that uses subdomains and so i use the hosts file on my my to point for example achme.mycompany.dev to localhost.

How do i do this on the ipad to goto achme.mycompany.dev in the browser and it runs the local app on my imac ?

Hope this all makes sense!   Please help.

best regards
Rick

Comment: Use port 8080 with -p then just make the host accessible on the network.  Use the private ip, ie 192.x.x.x\10.x.x.x with that port 8080 to access it.  Simple networking will make it work as a host on the wireless network.

Comment: Would that it were so simple, Hitham. It should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am hoping that your macbook and iPad are on same network. Now go to "Open network preference". Check screenshot.

You will see an ip.

[image]

then from ipad open: your_ip:3000

Comment: This is unbelievably useful. Well done and thank you!

Answer (score 28):

I'm providing an update for anyone who's using Rails 4, has followed the steps in the accepted answer, and still can't connect to the app via `development_machine_ip:3000`. The reason being that somewhere around version 4, Rails changed the default binding address from `0.0.0.0` to only `localhost`. By default this allows you to only access the Rails app via `localhost:3000` or `127.0.0.1:3000` - which is fine in most cases.

Now if you'd like to access the app from a different device on your network, you can use the `-b` option when starting the server and specify a binding address of `0.0.0.0`

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

This will bind on ALL interfaces including localhost and the IP assigned by your network. You should now be able to access the app via `development_machine_ip:3000`.

Comment: thanks, I couldn't do it with the accepted answer but with yours I can access but rails is having problems to access files, it throws  ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied @ utime_internal  Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

Answer (score 6):

I use <strike>[proxylocal](http://proxylocal.com/)</strike>  [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for this:

```
$ ngrok http 3000
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                       (Ctrl+C to quit)

Session Status                online
Account                       Sergio (Plan: Free)
Version                       2.2.8
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://be278635.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000
Forwarding                    https://be278635.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Now you can open http://be278635.ngrok.io from your ipad without worrying about your machine's ip address.

Comment: proxylocal.com seems to be dead. I use [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com) from much the same thing-- create a (temporary) tunnel to my local machine that can be accessed from a public-facing domain/URL.

Answer (score 4):

If the subdomain is just going to 127.0.0.1:3000 (or whatever) you should be able to access it the same way by going to your machine's local IP address with the same supplied port number. I look at my rails app on my phone all the time.

If you have virtual hosts or something set up, it's probably going to be more complicated than that.

Comment: Run `ifconfig` in a terminal to get your local IP address

Comment: This should work.  You may have to open up port 3000 in your mac's firewall,  but pointing your iPad to your iMac's ip address should work.  That's how I test all my apps.

Comment: so i can goto achme.mydomain.dev on my ipad and it will look at my imacs host file ???      how does this work ?   thanks a lot!

Answer (score -3):

For this, you would either need to jailbreak your iPad to edit the /etc/hosts file, or add a DNS entry in your router (assuming your router is your DNS server).

One of those two sounds like the easiest.

Comment: what?  He doesn't want to run the app on his iPad.  He wants to access the app through the server running on his iMac.

Comment: ctilley79  yes you are correct i only want to access the app to test using ipad browser but run it on imac

Comment: @ctilley79 that is what RFC1337 intended.  The /etc/hosts file edit on the iPad would be for the iPad to *find* the webserver on the iMac.

Comment: I apologize.  I didn't see the need to do that if you navigate directly to the ip address the mac is running on.  Modifying the host file is unnecessary.