# More efficient way to view changes on a mobile device without pushing rails app to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, heroku

Probably a dumb question:

Right now, to see changes made in development, I run `rails s` and see the changes on the local version of my site.  To see how changes look on my phone, I currently commit to Git (no matter how small the changes) and then push to heroku.  This takes some time and results in lots of commits and deployments for minor changes (i.e. CSS stuff).

What is a more efficient way to test changes for rails web apps on mobile?

NOTE: I am aware I can shrink my browser but it never fails I get different outcomes on my phone.

Any help is appreciated.

RELATED: [how do i run a development rails app / website on an ipod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621282/how-do-i-run-a-development-rails-app-website-on-an-ipod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) connect your phone to the same network that your local server is running on and point it to http://[your server's ip]:3000

2) use the [XCode iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator.html) and/or [the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Nitrous.io which is a cloud development environment. I like it because not only can I view my work on mobile, but since it's a hosted URL, I can share it with others while my server is running.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use ngrok

https://ngrok.com/

which gives you a way to make an external tunnel to the outside world (for free) so you can use it outside of your local network